# Какой пакет нужен в atom'е, например чтобы после <head> он автоматически ставил </head>?

Tags: html, atom

Очень не удобно без такого, поэтому временно на sublim'e

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[autoclose](https://atom.io/packages/autoclose) - нужно установить отдельно, для автозакрытия html тегов

[bracket-matcher](https://atom.io/packages/bracket-matcher) - для автозакрытия скобок и кавычек (можно найти среди установленных по умолчанию пакетов)